# Media files don't preview - Django

Tags: django, image, media

I have a problem with media files. I read everything on Net and tried all offered solutions but nothing works.

This is settings.py:

```html
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")


STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, './myapp/static/'), )

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

This is urls.py:

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('application/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('application/accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('application/', include('myapp.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is part of template where image needs to show:

```html
{% if word.image %}
    <img src="{{ word.image.url }}" alt="img" class="wordImg">
{% else %}
    <p class="wordPar">No image to preview</p>
{% endif %}
```

Everything seems fine to me but obviously there is a mistake, because image cannot preview. I get this:

[image cannot preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifzLg.png)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Inspect the html page and check what is the URL for the image and compare it with the actual image where its placed.